# Identifier "IXMLDOMSchemaCollectionPtr" is undefined

Tags: c++, import, msxml, msxml6

I am trying to use the msxml library.

Here's a sample of my code :

```
#include <msxml6.h>

...

int validate_cii() {
    // Create a schema cache
    IXMLDOMSchemaCollectionPtr pSchemaCache;
    ...
}
```

I get this error : `Identifier "IXMLDOMSchemaCollectionPtr" is undefined`.

To install MSXML I have downloaded the msxml6.dll and I put it in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` and `C:\Windows\System32`, shouldn't it be the only thing I have to do to install a library and use it?

I've seen [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/cc507432(v=vs.85)) saying that I should install MSXML SDK but I can't find it. It should be [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb190622(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) but it looks like it isn't.

I use Visual Studio Community 2022 and C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms765540(v=vs.85)) explaining how to properly import MSXML.

```
#import <msxml6.dll> raw_interfaces_only
using namespace MSXML2;
```